# Upload Files Library | ci-phpunit-test

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

While running tests with `ci-phpunit-test`, `$this->upload->do_upload('order_file')` always returns a **false**. Is it because its not loading the library correctly?

This is my controller:

```
class Orders extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('order_model');
    }

    # POST /orders/upload | accepts multi-part form encoded
    public function upload()
    {
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => '../order_uploads/',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg',
            'encrypt_name' => true
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        # upload the file
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('order_file')) {
             // do something here
         }
}
```

and my tests

```
<?php
class OrderControllerTest extends TestCase
{
   public function testupload() {
     $this->request('POST', 'orders/upload?order_file=some_file.jpg');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `do_upload` expects a **file** in the `$_FILES` array and not a post or get var in their respective superglobal array.

I don't see any way you can programmatic unit test this function.